# Unable to run the jar file in MacOs

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, executable-jar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [unsupported major .minor version 51.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0)

I am learning java these days.I created an application in it and created an executable Jar file of it.
The jar file is working properly in Windows 7 but when i tried to run the same Jar file in Macos then i get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/redfire/screen/ScreenShare : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
 at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
 at FinalJavaScreenShare.InitialiseScreenShare(FinalJavaScreenShare.java:150)
 at FinalJavaScreenShare.GetServerData(FinalJavaScreenShare.java:134)
 at FinalJavaScreenShare.main(FinalJavaScreenShare.java:46)
```

What could be the reason for such an error. I want to know whether i have to create separate Jar file for different OS or is there any issue with the current version of the Jar.

**Note: I am using Eclipse Helios for the creation of the Jar file.**

Please help me .Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: The short answer is, check the version of Java you are compiling with compared to the version you have installed

Answer (score 0):

This has been flagged as a duplicate based on your 1st question (please focus on one question per ..question).  I will address the other part of it.

> Do I have to create separate Jar file for different OS or is there any issue with the current version of the Jar?

No & yes respectively.

The important thing here is to ensure the [cross-compilation options of `javac`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#crosscomp-options) are used to compile code for the minimum Java run-time version that supports it.